# How to add Launchpad PPA of different Ubuntu versions to my Machine?

Tags: 14.04, apt, ppa, launchpad

I want to add a certain Launchpad PPA via `add-apt-repository` to my machine. Is it possible to add the PPAs of several or even all Ubuntu Versions to my Machine? This is just for comparing the different versions with each other.

**UPDATE**

If it is possible, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

That's definitely possible, but you shouldn't be doing that as different binary packages have different dependencies which usually are only available in specific versions of Ubuntu.

By adding a ppa with packages build for another version of ubuntu, and installing the packages you'll either end up in messed up system, or won't be able to install the packages due to missing dependencies.
Though it might work for a packages with a very limited number of dependencies.

Comment: how can I do this? what is the command?